# Heroku app moving to VPS, dns fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I've removed my app from Heroku, but I forgot to remove my custom domain from heroku. Now i'm stuck with two versions of one site. .nl is working correctly, www..nl is giving me the error message "Heroku | No such app"
What to do? I've already edited my DNS records, but still doesn't fix this problem,

Many thanks,

Comment: might be it take time to update dns record max 24 hours as per my knowledge.wait for some time and check

Comment: It's been over 10 hours when i did edit it, so i've to wait longer.

Comment: could you copy the output of the `dig` command? `dig @8.8.8.8 www.yourdomain.nl` and `dig @8.8.8.8 yourdomain.nl`

Comment: The output of the dig commando:
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


Without www.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a Heroku message, then your DNS is still pointing to Heroku.  There is no Heroku setting that could cause it to take control unless your DNS is sending traffic there.

If **http://something.nl** is working, but **http://www.something.nl** is not, then you probably didn't change all of your DNS settings properly.

The only other option I can think of is that your webserver on your VPS is routing traffic from www to the Heroku app, that is very unlikely though.

Last option... wait longer for DNS propagation if everything is correct.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Did a full reset to original DNS settings, point to my VPS and Google apps, and wait a few hours. Now it's working perfectly. 

Thanks!